# Are they going to reveal how the virus spread and who made it?

Tags: the-walking-dead

After watching almost 5 seasons of *The Walking Dead* I expected that some of the mystery gets be revealed about "authors" of the virus and how it spread, but apparently the producers are not going to do that unless it happend in season 6. Are they going to reveal how the virus spread and who made it?

Comment: Kirkman has stated in the comic that he has no intention or desire to tell the origin. I'd guess the same will go for the show.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quite possibly no.

Executive producer [Robert Kirkman](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCt7K01pLLAhVD2BoKHe1zDHUQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRobert_Kirkman&usg=AFQjCNGHlmAolXtQX3rpIDTMpmgf-IZ5nw) [discussed this](http://mashable.com/2015/04/14/fear-the-walking-dead/) at a packed panel in Las Vegas, stating:

> "[Learning the origins] is not the priority in Walking Dead; that's
>   not the priority in Fear The Walking Dead," Kirkman told a packed
>   panel at the NAB Show in Las Vegas. "Every other story deals with that
>   stuff and we're concerned about the heart."

He then went on to say:

> "I know the story, but I've never bothered to write it down," he said.
>   "Let's hope I don't die."

So *he knows* how the zombie outbreak started, but he never considered it interesting enough to be the main focus of the show.

Given this, it's possible we'll never have the reasons revealed - it's impossible to tell right now.

Comment: While not exactly a specific description of the origins of the virus and the very early stages of its outbreak, there are webisodes that illustrate some of the very early events of its spread, such as the current one airing on AMC showing walkers on airplanes. FTWD also talks about a flu or sickness that is spreading in multiple states. So it is possible to see _clues_ about its origin, but nothing definitive.

Comment: The weird thing is that there is not many zombie movies or stories that deals with the origins. World War Z looks for patient zero but doesn’t try to find how the virus originated. So it’s disappointing that Kirkman would say that because it’s simply not true.